# Jquery show/hide based on variable (not toggle)

Tags: jquery

In jQuery (I'm currently using 1.11.4), is there any inbuilt helper function to allow you to show/hide elements based on a variable?

For instance, at the moment to show/hide something based on a checkbox I do something like these two examples...

```
$("#myChk").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#otherEl").show();
  } else {
    $("#otherEl").hide();
  }
});

$("#myChk").on("click", function() {
  var $otherEl = $("#otherEl");
  ($(this).is(":checked") ? $otherEl.show() : $otherEl.hide());
});
```

Is there a single inbuilt function that I can't easily find in the documentation that allows something like...

```
$("#myChk").on("click", function() {
  $("#otherEl").showOrHide($(this).is(":checked"))
});
```

I'm pretty sure there isn't anything, but I thought I'd ask just in case.

I'm aware of [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) but that is based on the current visibility of the element, not an external variable.

(And if anybody is aware of anything similar for `.slideUp` and `.slideDown` that would also be useful.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just needed to read further down in the documentation. `.toggle()` allows you to pass true/false to set the display:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

> display
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Use true to show the element or false to hide
>   it.

So you can pass `$(this).is(":checked")` to it, e.g. `.toggle( $(this).is(":checked") )`

Comment: I'm going to use the comment by the OP on the duplicate question... "Ok, so I am an idiot and need to RTFM before I ask questions.".  Thanks for your answer... will mark as answer when I can

Comment: In my exceptionally limited defence, I read the first of the definitions (`.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )`) and assumed if I passed in a boolean it would be taken as the `[duration]`... you are completely correct that I failed to continue down the definitions

Comment: @freefaller don't sweat it; happens to all of us

Comment: If you are passing any variable, assure to force it to a boolean, `.toggle(!!show)` otherwise you might pass `undefined` and then it will just toggle... good luck finding the bug afterwards.